# UserWarning: The value of the smallest subnormal for <class 'numpy.float32'> type is zero

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/getlimits.py:89: UserWarning: The value of the smallest subnormal for <class 'numpy.float32'> type is zero.` after upgrading python from python3.6 to python3.9 and also upgraded numpy to 1.22.2

Below is my requirements.txt.

```
aenum==3.1.8
alembic==1.7.6
amqp==5.0.9
arrow==1.2.2
asgiref==3.4.1
attrs==21.4.0
babel==2.9.1
billiard==3.6.4.0
celery==5.2.3
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.11
click==8.0.3
click-didyoumean==0.3.0
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.2.0
coreapi==2.3.3
coreschema==0.0.4
cvxpy==1.1.18
deprecated==1.2.13
django==3.2.5
django-extensions==3.1.5
django-prometheus==2.0.0
djangorestframework==3.13.1
ecos==2.0.10flower==0.9.2
gevent==21.12.0
greenlet==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.3
intervaltree==3.1.0
itypes==1.2.0
jinja2==3.0.3
kombu==5.2.3
logbook==1.5.3
mako==1.1.6
markupsafe==2.0.1
nptime==1.1
numpy==1.22.2
osqp==0.6.2.post5
packaging==21.3
paho-mqtt==1.3.1
pandas==1.3.5
pika==1.2.0
prometheus-client==0.13.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.28
pyparsing==3.0.7
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.3
qdldl==0.1.5.post0
redis==4.1.2
requests==2.27.1
scipy==1.8.0
scs==3.1.0
six==1.16.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
sqlalchemy==1.4.29
sqlalchemy-utils==0.38.2
sqlparse==0.4.2
tornado==6.1
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==1.26.8
vine==5.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.5
wrapt==1.13.3
zope-event==4.5.0
zope-interface==5.4.0
```

The above warning triggering in docker container but not in locally and also it happens in celery applications. Could you please help me out why is this warning triggering?

Comment: Do you have opencv installed? [opencv screws with floating-point settings.](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/20895)

Comment: If it's not opencv, something else probably screwed with floating-point handling.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I do not use it in my requirements.txt.  Thank you for your reply

Comment: It may not be in your requirements.txt, but it could be a transitive dependency, or installed for some other reason.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I do generate requirements.txt using pip-compile with requirements.in. It will add transitive dependencies in requirements.txt if any other packages have it. This warning I see for services where I am running celery workers (Kombu, celery, redis) and also I do not see this warning in my locally but it happens in Docker container

Answer (score 4):

This might be a relevant discussion. https://moyix.blogspot.com/2022/09/someones-been-messing-with-my-subnormals.html

The author has identified certain Python packages that are messing around with the global processor flags that define how subnormals/denormals are handled. Gevent is one of them (and on your list).